# implementing chi-square to find distance between 2 SIFT feature

Tags: sift, chi-squared

I am trying to implement chi-square which algorithm is :

```
Distance= 1/2* Ei((Xi-Yi)^2/Xi+Yi)
instead of euclidean distance which algorithm is:
Distance= Sqrt(E(Xi-Yi)^2)
in calculating distance between 2 SIFT feature (128 dimensional vector),
```

my problem is the divider in chi- square could be 0 and it will make the distance bacome NaN. Should i make the divider into 1 or ignore it ? or there was another chi-square algorithm for calculating SIFT feature ?

Answer (score 0):

If values are non-negative (like histogram values), the only way to zero divisor is Xi==Yi==0 and so the distance for this *i* is 0.
So you only have to check for zero:

```
sum = 0;
for( i.... ) {
  auto div = Xi + Yi;
  if( div == 0 ) continue;
  sum += (Xi-Yi)*(Xi-Yi)/div;
}
return sum/2;
```

Answer (score -1):

Check for 0 and throw an exception in your calculate method. I can't see how dividing by 1 makes any sense?

```
if ( (Xi+Yi) == 0 )
   throw new Exception("bad divider")
```

Handle the exception in calling code. (Would help if you indicate the language you are programming in.)

Comment: so we don't include it in the calculation ?

Comment: If your divider is zero then I don't see that it makes any mathematical sense to do the calculation? So, trap the error and display a warning to the user indicating invalid parameters were entered. I'm not sure under what circumstance that Xi and Yi would equal opposites of each other? Perhaps you need to validate the inputs the user interface layer?

Comment: I'm using it to calculate the distance between 2 SIFT descriptor, so it will be often to get Xi + Yi equals to zero.

Comment: Just replace all zeros is all SIFTs with ones. It wouldn`t make you a big difference in descriptors.